# Updating deprecated SASS syntax for color multiplication

Tags: sass

In the old versions of SASS, it was possible to multiply color values by a regular number:

```css
$white: #E2E2E2;
color: $white * 0.7; /* results in #9E9E9E */
```

I'm working with code that used this extensively on grays. Since this syntax is now considered deprecated, I need to find an alternative which produces the same result.

There is a [recommendation](https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/2491) to use `scale-color`:

```
color: scale-color($white, $lightness: -30%);
```

Even though it produces the same result and the new value can be calculated easily (*factor* - 1) it won't work equally for factors greater than 1:

```css
$black: #050505;
color: $black * 2; /* results in #A0A0A0 */
color: scale-color($black, $lightness: 100%); /* results in pure white */
```

Is there a better and unified way to update this to a new conforming syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using arithmetic functions and want to achieve exactly the same result:

```scss
@function colorArithmetic($color, $scale: 1, $offset: 0) {
  $red: (red($color) * $scale) + $offset;
  $green: (green($color) * $scale) + $offset;
  $blue: (blue($color) * $scale) + $offset;
  @return rgb($red, $green, $blue)
}
```

For example u can replace this:

```scss
$red: $globalRed * $scale;
$blue: $globalBlue * $scale;
$green: $globalGreen * $scale;
$yellow: $globalYellow * $scale;
```

To this code:

```scss
$red: colorArithmetic($globalRed, $scale);
$blue: colorArithmetic($globalBlue, $scale);
$green: colorArithmetic($globalGreen, $scale); 
$yellow: colorArithmetic($globalYellow, $scale);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `darken` and `lighten` functions

`lighten($color, $amount)` : Makes a color lighter.

`darken($color, $amount)` : Makes a color darker.

[Sass Doc](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html)

Comment: I know. But how would you calculate the amount, to get the same result?